# file command does not recognize perl module

Tags: file-command

The file command (Debian Jessie) in does not recognize some Perl modules.
For example: /usr/share/perl5/XML/SAX.pm (from libxml-sax-perl) gives:

```
$ file /usr/share/perl5/XML/SAX.pm
/usr/share/perl5/XML/SAX.pm: C++ source, ASCII text
```

The module starts with:

```
# $Id$

package XML::SAX;

use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT_OK);
```

When I remove the first two line, file sees it as a Perl module:

```
$ file tt
tt: Perl5 module source, ASCII text
```

Still, other modules starting with comment, such as `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2/Encode.pm` are correctly identified.

Is this a bug?
And where do I find the uncompiled mime data for `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc`?

Answer (score 4):

The uncompiled data (it's not MIME data) for `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc` is in [`Magdir`](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir) in the [`file(1)`](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) [source code](https://github.com/file/file). The Perl magic in particular is defined in [`Magdir/perl`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/perl). The issue you're seeing has been [fixed](https://github.com/file/file/commit/a000ab5f836cd668d0aad4b22104d8c7aeec5b8e); the fix is available in `file` versions 5.23 and later.

Comment: I have version 5.22 indeed; thanks!

Comment: @WyboDekker If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.